# How to preview images after uploading in Odoo V10?

Tags: image, odoo, open-source, odoo-10

There is `ir.attachment` model available for uploading URL and files but I want to upload images and that can be viewed on the uploading form UI-view.

Is there any way I can do it as I haven't found anything on this related to Odoo V10.

[image]

How can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

odoo app available on odoo apps page please go throw this url may be it will help you [https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/category/Extra%20Tools/browse?search=image+preview]

Comment: No, it doesn't work. So is there any other way in which we can preview the image

Comment: only way to achieve you task, is inherit base slide bar js and refer how to extract documnet and view it

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Add this code in your .py

```py
attachment = fields.Many2many("ir.attachment", string="Attachment")
```

and .xml

```xml
<field name ="attachment" widget="many2many_binary"/>
```

I hope it works for you.